# How to send an email in wordpress without plugins

Tags: php, wordpress

I create a plugin for feedback using a shortcode. It doesn't issue errors, but it doesn't send anything to the mail either.
How to send an email to wordpress without plugins?
Here is my PHP code:

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: myShortcodeForForms
Description: Plugin to create a feedback form using shortcode
Version: 1.0.0
Author: Author Name
*/
add_shortcode( 'addForm', 'add_forms' );
function add_forms() {
    return logic();
}

function logic() {

    ?>
    <form id="contact" method="get">
    <h3>Feedback form</h3>
        <div id="note"></div>
        <div id="fields">
            <p><input type="text" name="nameGet" id="author" placeholder="Name" required> <label for="author">Enter your name</label></p>
            <p><input type="email" name="emailGet" id="email" placeholder="E-mail" required> <label for="email">Email</label></p>
            <p><input type="text" name="subGet" id="url" placeholder="Subject" required> <label for="url">Message subject</label></p>
            <p><textarea name="messageGet" cols="1" rows="10" id="Text" placeholder="Enter the message text here" required></textarea></p>
            <p><button type="submit" id="submit" class="go">Send message</button></p>
        </div>
    </form>
    <?php

    if($_GET['nameGet'] != null && $_GET['emailGet'] != null && $_GET['subGet'] != null && $_GET['messageGet'] != null) {
        $headers = 'From: My Name <from@example.com>' . "\r\n";

        wp_mail('to@example.com', 'Hello', 'Hello world!', $headers);
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Maybe you need setup your mail server for example - sendmail or use some service.

Comment: from@example.com and to@example.com is a pseudo email. I use gmail in my code.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the action hidden input so that we can trigger the more specific hook related to our contact form submission

also you need to add action attribute to `<form>` tag

**add_action** hook allows you to create your own handler for GET or POST request

I think your code should be something like this

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: myShortcodeForFormsx
Description: Plugin to create a feedback form using shortcode
Version: 1.0.0
Author: Author Name
*/
add_shortcode( 'addForm', 'add_forms' );
function add_forms() {
    return logic();
}

function logic() {
ob_start();
?>
    <form action="<?php echo esc_url( admin_url('admin-post.php') ); ?>" method="post">
    <h3>Feedback form</h3>
        <div id="note"></div>
        <div id="fields">
            <p><input type="text" name="nameGet" id="author" placeholder="Name" required> <label for="author">Enter your name</label></p>
            <p><input type="email" name="emailGet" id="email" placeholder="E-mail" required> <label for="email">Email</label></p>
            <p><input type="text" name="subGet" id="url" placeholder="Subject" required> <label for="url">Message subject</label></p>
            <p><textarea name="messageGet" cols="1" rows="10" id="Text" placeholder="Enter the message text here" required></textarea></p>
            <input type="hidden" name="action" value="my_contact_form">
            <p><button type="submit" id="submit" class="go">Send message</button></p>
        </div>
    </form>
    <?php
return ob_get_clean();

}


function prefix_send_email_to_admin() {
  if($_POST['nameGet'] != null && $_POST['emailGet'] != null && $_POST['subGet'] != null && $_POST['messageGet'] != null) {
      $headers = 'From: My Name <from@example.com>' . "\r\n";
      wp_mail('to@example.com', 'Hello', 'Hello world!', $headers);
  }
}
add_action( 'admin_post_nopriv_my_contact_form', 'prefix_send_email_to_admin' );
add_action( 'admin_post_my_contact_form', 'prefix_send_email_to_admin' );

?>
```